# ASP.NET Core - How to Use Identity Services Across Databases?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

For the sake of saving time and getting my point across here's an analogy. 
Let's say I am creating a chain of supermarkets. Each supermarket has its own database and employees can login through a web app. Now the way I have it structured is there is one database for handling logins to the app and then the employee can select their supermarket from a list to then connect to that database

The issue I'm now facing is how do I authorize users in this separate database? The supermarket may have a manager who would need to access everything, a standard employee who may only be allowed to see their timetable or perhaps even a director who would be allowed access to certain supermarkets databases and see everything in those. An employee could work at multiple stores, where their level of access differs at each store.

I understand this is where Roles and Claims come in. I currently have an IdentityDbContext on the login database with all the userclaims, roleclaims etc, but these should be specific to each supermarkets database so I don't think they should be stored in the login database. Does anyone know of a possible fix? A way to possibly keep AspNetUserLogins table in the Login database and AspNetRoles,claims etc in the supermarkets database?

**What I've tried/thought about:**
I've thought about having IdentityDbContext on both databases, but then the user would have to login again to get to the supermarket database. I don't want this, it needs to be a seamless experience where the user can jump between supermarkets by the click of a button.

Comment: Why should the 'supermarket' claims be in the 'supermarket' database?   A central identity server should contain all the claims for the whole system IMO.

Comment: as you already said, the user data has to be stored inside the database of the supermarket,
what i would do, the login database has a token which represents a user inside the shop database, if the shop gets switched, the user gets programmatically re authenticated with his right, which he has on the active database

Comment: Thankyou @Isparia, I'll have a look into that and see what I can get working :)